# Sheaf Cohomology on Zariski-Riemann Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, valuation-theory, function-fields, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Can sheaf cohomology on the Zariski-Riemann spaces give some sort of classification for field extensions (even just for function fields)? If not, are there any significant or useful results (e.g. for function fields) obtained by this approach? Thanks!